# Get products which do not have any custom option

Tags: collection

i have to get the products which do not contain any custom option, but not using has_options flag. The aim of doing this if the products do not contain any option, i have to set has_options to 0 progmatically(may be through magmi).

Is there any filter statement can select the products which do not have have custom options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It not proper way to get non custom option products using has_options field.has_option is set to 1 when it bundle.

Good idea to join the table `catalog_product_option` to collection and and using join query check product have  custom option or not

Here
**Step1:** Get Collection of product `which have  option  and then group them  by product id`

```
$Option=Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_option_collection')->addFieldToSelect('product_id');
$Option->getSelect()->group('main_table.product_id');
```

**Step2:** filter `product collection by excluding those products getting from step1`

```
   $entityIds = new Zend_Db_Expr($Option->getSelect()->__toString());
    $Collection=Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
    echo $Collection->getSelect()->where('e.entity_id not in(?)', $entityIds);
```

Comment: you are welcome.I have give upvote for your question