# How to get all product having custom options as radio type?

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to get all product which have custom option as radio type.
How to load product having custom option radio type. ?

Answer (score 1):

**Step1:** Get Collection of product which have  option as **type radio**  and then group them  by product id

```
$Option=Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_option_collection')
    ->addFieldToSelect('product_id')
    ->addFieldToFilter('type','radio');
$Option->getSelect()->group('main_table.product_id');
```

**Step2:** filter product collection by those products getting from **step1**

```
$entityIds = new Zend_Db_Expr($Option->getSelect()->__toString());
$Collection=Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$Collection->getSelect()->where('e.entity_id in(?)', $entityIds);
```

[Source](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/61177/45103)

Answer (score 0):

```
$options = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option')
->getCollection()
->addFieldToFilter('type', array('eq','radio'))
->distinct(true)
;
foreach ($options as $key => $option) {
    if($option->getData('type') == 'radio'){
        $productId = $option->getProductId();
        echo $productId;
    }
}
```